# Eclipse java launcher

Tags: java, eclipse, project, launch

I have installed Android SDK in Eclipse and programmed/run different programms by using it. Then I tried to create a normal Java project in eclipse and tried to run it but it does not work anymore!?
I tried by running it with 
RunAs->Java Application
but nothing happens, then I tried to Run it with RunConfigurations, and set the Project name. But I don't get any Results??

Comment: Is your console not marked to recognize the change of STDOUT but is marked only for error. In such cases console is not highlighted.

Comment: so what do I have to configure?

Comment: What kind of programs did your run before ? Which release of eclipse and SDK did you install ?